# How to add new .php page into test rail?

Tags: testrail

Official guide told us, that we should place .php page near index.php (for example).
But how I can do it, if I have test rail installation on the cloud (test rail.net)?

I need to add buttons to start our tests. But i can send request from javascript only to the same domain. So, I need a custom php page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if you are on the cloud.

[[source](https://discuss.gurock.com/t/custom-reports-in-testrail-cloud/2570/2?u=gmcdonald)]